# WebRTC : while creating second peer connection - fail to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, openwebrtc

I am working on webrtc chat app.
system1 : peer1, peer3 | system2 : peer2, peer4

What I did ?
For video call, I am creating one peer1, peer2, and that peer1 very successfully communicate with peer2 (consider video call only).

What I want to do?
I want, peer3 can communicate with new peer4(meanwhile I don't want to disconnect peer1-->peer2).

What happening ?
When I am creating peer3, on that time " navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia " getting errors !!!! (I am not using SSL) and new peer3 can't create !.

So, please tell me your suggestions regarding above problem.

It is possible to only peer1 can communicate with other any peer(bidirectional communication)??

Comment: are u getting this error `DevicesNotFoundError` ??

Comment: i have used webRtc previously and it worked just fine. but recently since new browser updates i'm getting this error. `DevicesNotFoundError` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378750/getusermedia-devicesnotfounderror-thrown-in-latest-browsers)

Comment: @Akshaykomarla Not actually. Right now everything working fine accept parallel two call is not working.

Comment: which browser and version you are using? mine in Firefox - 57.0.4 , Chrome - 63 its giving me error. but in previous version its fine

Comment: @Akshaykomarla same as you mentioned.  Use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() method with adapter.js. 

And upVote this question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the browser failing to capture video from the webcam if it's *already in use* by another browser or another tab in the same browser. For example, Firefox 57 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine exhibits this behavior (Chrome does not).