# getusermedia DevicesNotFoundError thrown in latest browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I have been using getUserMedia() for WebRtc for a while now but since the latest update of browsers I have not been able to use this. On previous versions worked fine.

[image]

Affected browsers' versions
Firefox - 57.0.4 , 
Chrome - 63.0.3239.132

Example code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": false }, function (stream) {
  console.log(stream);
  localStream = stream;

},logError);
```

Also check this if anyone is getting this error in google sample code
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

Is there any work around for this issue? Need help.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what causes the error.... _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."_

Comment: example code added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. In newer versions when we specify the constraints `{ audio: true, video: true }` either of which ever we specify as true that corresponding hardware need to be present. otherwise it will throw `DevicesNotFoundError` .

Here is the code i used. i don't have a web cam in local machine so specified video as false.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false})
.then(function(stream) {
   /* use the stream */ 
})
.catch(function(err) {
   /* handle the error */
});
```

Comment: use navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() to find out what device types are available.

Comment: Some webcams don't have audio which means that requesting  "audio: true" would cause the error.